# Is there a command to typeset the Unicode symbol 'DIVISION TIMES' (U+22C7)?

Tags: symbols

[Recently I became aware](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1861245/%e2%8b%87-division-times-operator-in-unicode-u22c7) of the Unicode symbol 'DIVISION TIMES' (U+22C7), which is ⋇. That is, it is a hybrid of times and division and the intended semantics ought to be the multiplicative analogue of the well-known ±,  which can be typeset in LaTeX by `\pm`.

Is there a command like `\pm` for getting ⋇? <strike>(Detexify does not recognize it.)</strike>

If there is no command, how would one go about typesetting this in LaTeX?

I am given to understand some variants of LaTeX support Unicode, so it would be non-issue there, but I would like to know about other ways.

Comment: The question is mainly idle curiosity, I hope this is alright. But I  liked this site since a long time, yet never joined, so I jumped on that opportunity.

Comment: I *had* searched for the Unicode on the site; not sure how I missed it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

The command you are looking for is `\divideontimes`, can be used in mathmode only, and requires the `amssymb`-package.

Comment: This is very strange. We were two that  could not find it there. Maybe we did not draw it well enough. I now tried again, and there it is! Thanks for the help.

Comment: @quid DeTeXify is a fickle tool. btw: if that solves your problem, feel free to accept the answer.

Comment: @quid: I managed to find it too; curiously I still think my drawing that _didn't_ work was better: http://henning.makholm.net/misc/divideontimes.png (Don't judge; they were made on a trackpad).

Comment: @HenningMakholm I found it when I drew the 'X' (starting top left -> down right, down left -> top right) first, then the '-' and last the two dots as circles (top first).